# Select menu for mobile website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I wanna to make select menu for mobile website ..
i put select html code in my page

```
  <select id="menu_mobile"> 
<option value="" selected="selected">Navigation</option>
<option value="http://kudu.com.sa/en/about/who-we-are">  Who we are</option>
<option value="index.html">  Home</option>
<option value="index.html">  --Profile</option>
<option value="index.html">  --Franchise</option>
<option value="index.html">  --CSR</option>
<option value="index.html">  Home</option>

</select>
```

but when i open my site on iphone
it's only select not click

how can i fix it

Comment: You mean it's not linking to index.html?

Comment: It's not clear what are you asking here..

Comment: This is **not** how to make a navigation. Use a normal `ul`.

Comment: @BramVanroy you misread OP's question. OP is making a drop down menu

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean the browser does not navigate to the value of the `<select>`.

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('#select').change( function() {
      location.href = $(this).val();
   }
});

<form action="">
    <select id="select">
        <option value="">Choose a site</option>
        <option value="/internal/location.htm">Location</option>
        <option value="http://external.site.com/">Other</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

## JavaScript

```
<form>
    <select onchange="window.location.href=this.form.URL.options[this.form.URL.selectedIndex].value" name="URL">
        <option value="">Choose a site</option>
        <option value="/internal/location.htm">Location</option>
        <option value="http://external.site.com/">Other</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: i also use this java script code 

          $(function() {
    $("#menu_mobile ").change(function()
    {
        document.location.href = $(this).val();
    });
      
      });

Comment: define `not work`. Any JS error showing in development console ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This One

```
$("select").change(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

its working [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FGxWC/) 
i think you havent add a jquery to your code